How to rotate nodes around their center without displacing the location
I would like to rotate with a different angle the rectangle nodes A,B, C, D and E of this plot:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    reader/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=#1, 
                         minimum width=4mm, minimum height=14mm}
    ]
    
    \draw[help lines, gray!30] (0,-7) grid (10,7);
    \pgfmathsetseed{12} % 

    %
    \node[reader=blue!30] (R1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[above] at (R1.north) {{Reader}};

    
    \foreach \i/\label in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{random(6,9)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{random(-2,3.5)}
                 
                    \node[, draw=black, fill=green!30, minimum width=2pt, minimum height=20pt, rotate ={0}, anchor=center,
                    scale=0.75, ] (\label) at (\x,\y)  {\label};    
            
            }
    
            \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (B.west) -- (A.east);
            \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (A.east) -- (E.west);
            \draw[latex-latex, , draw=blue, line width=0.5mm] (E.west) -- (D.east) node[midway, above, sloped] {\large{$d_{DE}$}};
            \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (D.east) -- (C.west);
        
            \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (B.west) node[midway, above, sloped] {\large{$d_{2}$}};
            \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (C.west) node[midway, above, sloped] (D3) {};
            \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (A.west) node[pos=0.7, above, sloped] (D1) {\large{$d_{1}$}};
        
            \path[] (D1) -- (D3) node[midway, scale=1.3] {$\vdots$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I have tried some variations like using scope to make the rotation but it changes the random position of the nodes. Can I use the random positions (\x,\y) and change just the rotation with different angle for each node, for example, around the center of the node?

What would be wrong with adding another variable (the angle \ang) to the \foreach loop? You can then use it for the node parameter rotate={\ang}.

@BanDoP That will rotate around the origin, won't it?

Together with anchor=center the parameter rotate={\ang} should roate around the center of the node. Is this not what you want?

Not sure what the result is meant to be, but you can use rotate around={<angle>:<coordinate>) to rotate around a point other than the origin, such as the centre of a node.
This can be combined with the addition of a third variable, as BanDoP suggested.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  reader/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=#1, 
    minimum width=4mm, minimum height=14mm}
  ]
  
  \draw[help lines, gray!30] (0,-7) grid (10,7);
  \pgfmathsetseed{12} % 
  
  \node[reader=blue!30] (R1) at (0,0) {};
  \node[above] at (R1.north) {{Reader}};
  
  \foreach \i/\label/\j in {1/A/45, 2/B/90, 3/C/0, 4/D/125, 5/E/267} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{random(6,9)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{random(-2,3.5)}
    \coordinate (a) at (\x,\y);
    
    \node[, draw=black, fill=green!30, minimum width=2pt, minimum height=20pt, anchor=center,
    scale=0.75, rotate around={\j:(a)} ] (\label) at (a)  {\label};    
  }
  
  \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (B.west) -- (A.east);
  \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (A.east) -- (E.west);
  \draw[latex-latex, , draw=blue, line width=0.5mm] (E.west) -- (D.east) node[midway, above, sloped] {\large{$d_{DE}$}};
  \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (D.east) -- (C.west);
  
  \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (B.west) node[midway, above, sloped] {\large{$d_{2}$}};
  \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (C.west) node[midway, above, sloped] (D3) {};
  \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (A.west) node[pos=0.7, above, sloped] (D1) {\large{$d_{1}$}};
  
  \path[] (D1) -- (D3) node[midway, scale=1.3] {$\vdots$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The result looks somewhat unlikely to me, which is why I'm not sure this is what is wanted.

